# HTTP POST request to JIRA from Angular 4 project throwing ERROR 403

Tags: angular, http, post, jira

I am trying to execute an HTTP POST request to create a JIRA Issue ticket using Angular4.

Following is the snippet of code I'm using:

```
const username = 'username';
const password = 'password';
const params = '{' +
                  '"fields":{' +
                      '"project": {' +
                            '"key": "ABCD" },' +
                        '"summary": "' + this.form.value.summary + '",' +
                        '"description":"' + this.form.value.description + '",' +
                        '"issuetype": {' +
                          '"name" : "' + this.form.value.issuetype + '"},' +
                        '"customfield_10041": {"value": "' + this.form.value.storyType + '"}' +
                      '}' +
                  '}' ; 

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Host', 'https://jira-uat.in.here.com');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));

return this.http.post('https://someURI/rest/api/2/issue/', params , {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
```

Although I am able to successfully create a JIRA issue using POSTMAN (an HTTP client for testing web services), but when I try to run through my Angular project, it throws me the following error:

```
 ERROR: Response with status: 403 Forbidden for URL: https://someURI/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Any clue as to what am I missing out here?

When I try to compile the code, following are the REQUEST HEADERS that is passed -

```
 Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
 Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
 Authorization:Basic Z**********************h
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:149
 Content-Type:application/json
 Host:someURI
 Origin:http://evil.com/
 Referer:http://localhost:4200/someRoute
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

And following is are the RESPONSE HEADERS:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, no-transform
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 01 Aug 2017 17:35:41 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_jk/1.2.41
Set-Cookie:JIRA72ARD1SESSIONID=E558106054FA151216527F0A66C6D204; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:atlassian.xsrf.token=BO4R-SWLP-WXR5-89O4|b25695ca2bee6fbaa48e9cddcf023d851bfc5bf5|lin; Path=/; Secure
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AREQUESTID:1055x68000x1
X-ASEN:SEN-2026451
X-ASESSIONID:c993lp
X-AUSERNAME:username
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Seraph-LoginReason:OK
```

Not sure what is wrong in this that's causing the problem!

Comment: The JIRA REST API should provide a more detailed error description in the response content. I'm not familiar with Angular, but there should be a way to read this response content without throwing an error.